# How to use Highcharts to make a chart with quadrants

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, highcharts

I am looking to implement a chart like the one in the image. I need to be able to feed the chart with data so the percentages and the size of the squares should be able to change dynamically.

[image]

So here is my implementation so far using Highcharts:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    margin: [100,100,100,100],
    events: {
      load: function () {
        var ren = this.renderer,
        rightArrow = ['M', 0, 0, 'L', -5, 5, 'M', 0, 0, 'L', -5, -5],
        leftArrow = ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 5, -5, 'M', 0, 0, 'L', 5, 5],
        topArrow = ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 5, 5, 'M', 0, 0, 'L', -5, 5],
        bottomArrow = ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 5, -5, 'M', 0, 0, 'L', -5, -5];
        ren.path(rightArrow).attr({'stroke-width': 2,stroke: "black"}).translate(600,350).add();
        ren.path(leftArrow).attr({'stroke-width': 2,stroke: "black"}).translate(100,350).add();
        ren.path(topArrow).attr({'stroke-width': 2,stroke: "black"}).translate(350,100).add();
        ren.path(bottomArrow).attr({'stroke-width': 2,stroke: "black"}).translate(350,600).add();
      }
    }
  },
  title: false,
  tooltip: false,
  xAxis: {
    offset: -250,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    min: -100,
    max: 100,
    tickInterval: 10,
    labels: false,
    lineColor: 'black',
    lineWidth: 2,
    title: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    offset: -250,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    min: -100,
    max: 100,
    tickInterval: 10,
    labels: false,
    lineColor: 'black',
    lineWidth: 2,
    title: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      lineWidth: 1,
      allowPointSelect: false
    },
    series: {
      marker: {
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [[1,1],[1,55],[55,55],[55,1],[1,1]]
  }, {
    data: [[-1,1],[-1,25], [-25,25], [-25,1],[-1,1]]
  }, {
    data: [[-1,-1],[-1,-35],[-35,-35],[-35,-1],[-1,-1]]
  }, {
    data: [[1,-1],[1,-15],[15,-15],[15,-1],[1,-1]]
  }]
});
```

https://codepen.io/vassilis/pen/oPKPNr

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Noticed you added some sample code, is that code not doing what you need? If yes, please update the question with this information. Should also try to make sure the code is a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would use Highcharts `scatter` series type with calculated radius and data based on four values in array:

```
var data = [10, 20, 5, 60],
    series = [];

series.push({
    data: [
        [data[0] / 2, data[0] / 2, data[0] / 2]
    ]
});

series.push({
    data: [
        [data[1] / 2, -data[1] / 2, data[1] / 2]
    ]
});

series.push({
    data: [
        [-data[2] / 2, -data[2] / 2, data[2] / 2]
    ]
});

series.push({
    data: [
        [-data[3] / 2, data[3] / 2, data[3] / 2]
    ]
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        margin: [100, 100, 100, 100],
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var xAxis = this.xAxis[0];

                Highcharts.each(this.series, function(s) {
                    s.points[0].update({
                        marker: {
                            radius: xAxis.toPixels(-100 + Math.abs(s.points[0].x)) - 100
                        }
                    });
                });
                ...
            }
        }
    },
    ...
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            }
        }
    },
    series: series
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rkmyfseq/

Comment: Very nice! Much better than with areas... data make more sense with scatter. Thank you!